# Strange behavior storing function results in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

Please consider the following two modules. Module a.ml contains:

```
(* Calls f with multi-indices ranging from beginning multi-index, args,
   to the max multi-index (current arg is index). *)
let rec do_multi_call max_mindex ~f args index = 
  let dim = Array.length max_mindex in
  if dim = 0 then
    f args                                                                                                                                                               
  else (
    let rest = Array.sub max_mindex 1 (pred dim) in
    args.(index) <- 0;
    while (args.(index) <= max_mindex.(0)) do
      do_multi_call rest ~f args (succ index);
      args.(index) <- succ (args.(index));
    done )

(* Calls f with m-indices ranging from 0 to max_mindex. *)
let multi_call (max_mindex : int array) ~f =
  let n_indices = Array.length max_mindex in
  let initial_args = Array.make n_indices 0 in
  do_multi_call max_mindex f initial_args 0
```

Module b.ml contains:

```
open A

(* print int arrays *)
let print_index i = 
  Array.iter (Printf.printf "%d ") i;
  print_endline ""; in                                                                                

let d = [| 2 ; 3 |] in
let indices = Queue.create () in
let add_index i = ( 
  print_index i;
  Queue.add i indices) in
multi_call d add_index;
print_endline ""; 
Queue.iter print_index indices;
```

The goal is to generate all arrays ranging from `[| 0 ; 0 |]` to `[| 2 ; 3 |]`, storing them in `indices` in `b.ml`. However, the output I get is

```
0 0 
0 1 
0 2 
0 3 
1 0 
1 1 
1 2 
1 3 
2 0 
2 1 
2 2 
2 3 

3 4 
3 4 
3 4 
3 4 
3 4 
3 4 
3 4 
3 4 
3 4 
3 4 
3 4 
3 4
```

So the arrays are being generated correctly, but I can't seem to save them in some data structure (the queue `indices`, which is the second group of numbers in the output). I have also tried using lists and refs, but I keep getting the same result. Could someone explain why this is happening and how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you're adding the same array many times to your queue. Naturally when you print at the end you see  the final values in this same array printed out many times. You need to make copies of the array (since it's a mutable data structure).

One way to see the problem is to observe that you're creating an array just one time (in `multi_call`) but you're adding it to the queue many times (in `do_multi_call`).

**Update**

Here's a (relatively) simple example that has the same problem:

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.02.1

# let m n =
      let a = Array.make n 0 in
      let res = Array.make n [| |] in
      for i = 0 to n - 1 do
          for j = 0 to n - 1 do a.(j) <- i done;
          res.(i) <- a
      done;
      res;;
val m : int -> int array array = <fun>
# m 3;;
- : int array array = [|[|2; 2; 2|]; [|2; 2; 2|]; [|2; 2; 2|]|]
```

The (incorrect) idea of the code is to use `a` to set up each row of the matrix, then store it in the matrix. But there's only one `a`, so all the rows of the matrix are actually the same single array. This is a fairly common error using multidimensional arrays in OCaml. Your original code was similar, but with a queue rather than a matrix.

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing this. To clarify, in the 2nd paragraph are you referring to `initial_args` as the array I am creating one time?

Comment: Yes. You only call one function that creates an array: `Array.make`. You call it once in `multi_call`, and you call `multi_call` only once. (Correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: That's right. I initialize the array with zeros and `do_multi_call` then modifies its entries. What is confusing me is that in `add_index`, I print the array (this is the first group of numbers in the output), and immediately add the array to the queue. So it seems like both lines in the body of `add_index` are referring to different things when they refer to `i`...

Comment: There's just one array. It changes values while your code is running, but at the end there's just one array. So all the entries in your queue are the same.

Comment: Okay, so to work around this, would I have to make a copy of the array in `add_index` and then add that copy to the queue?

Comment: Yes, as I suggested :-)

Comment: Ah, I understand what's going on now, thanks! In `add_index`, changing `Queue.add i indices` to `Queue.add (Array.copy i) indices` does the trick. I wasn't thinking that the array was being passed by reference to `Queue.add`.